# Remove a Datarow from a Datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a windows application in which I am going to delete a datarow from a datatable.
But I got an exception.

> The given DataRow is not in the current DataRowCollection.

The code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRowView currentDataRowView = (DataRowView)DataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
DataRow row = currentDataRowView.Row;

dt.Rows.Remove(row); // exception here.
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

The datatable dt's information as the image shown.
[image: datatable dt]

I think that I already have casted datarowview to datarow.

**EDIT:**
dt was created from another DataGridView.

```
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DatGridView2.Rows)
                {
                    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell check = row.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
                    if (check.Value != null)
                    {
                        if ((bool)check.Value)
                        {
                            //this row has a checkBox set to true (tick is added)
                            //add this row to dataTable ...
                            DataRow myRow = (row.DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
                            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                            dr[0] = myRow[0];
                            dr[1] = myRow[1];
                            dr[2] = myRow[2];
                            dr[3] = myRow[3];
                            if (!dt.Rows.Contains(dr[0]))
                            {
                                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Your `dt` has no rows, so there is nothing to remove.

Comment: dt.Rows.Count=2. It has rows.

Comment: Where is dt getting the rows from?  Based on your code it is declared a few lines before trying to remove the row from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can reference a different DataTable than the one where `CurrentRow.DataBoundItem` is coming from.

Your `dt` DataTable is being constructed from DataGridView2 but `CurrentRow.DataBoundItem` is coming from DataGridView1.

You will have to find the matching row in DataGridView1 yourself before you can delete it.

Comment: Totally wrong. DataRow row = currentDataRowView.Row; I already defined it.

Comment: @Love I don't know then if you posted enough to answer it.  The `DataTable dt = new DataTable();` doesn't seem right, because it's "new" and doesn't seem to have any relationship to the DataGridView's datasource *prior* to you setting it.

Comment: See updated. Now the error becames "The given DataRow is not in the current DataRowCollection." Not sure why?

Comment: So as i understand, you have a gridview bounded with data, and on delete you fill the dt object with all the data that have check to true and then you try to delete from it. Maybe your trying to delete a row that wasn't added to your dt collection.

Comment: @Love Updated answer.  It looks like `row` is coming from a different DataGridView source, so the collection doesn't see the same reference.

Comment: But they are matching each other, I have two grids. I click cells on one of grid then add rows to the datatable and display in the other grid.Select the row in the other view to delete it from the datatable dt. What is wrong?

Comment: @Love They are not the same.  They may look the same, smell the same, but they came from different DataGridViews.  The collection of rows in dt is coming from DataGridView2, and then you are trying to delete the same row from DataGridView1.  They don't have the same reference.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I have a checkbox on the one of grid, I ticked it and add the row. In the other grid there is no such a check box. Maybe something wrong when I added the row to the datatable.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried your code, and it's working with no problem:

```
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        DataRowView currentDataRowView = (DataRowView)dataGridView1.Rows[0].DataBoundItem;
        DataRow row = currentDataRowView.Row;

        dt.Rows.Remove(row); 
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

So as i have wrote above, the error "The given DataRow is not in the current DataRowCollection" means that your trying to delete a row that is not in the DataTable "dt".